# order of data in mysql, displaying in order in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL database. I have a PHP page which grabs the rows of the database and displays the column data (in a format that I created) on the PHP page.

What I would like to do: display the data in order (of the date, there is a date that users set in a form that then submits it to the database and it goes into a date data type in the MySQL database).

Should I make sure that when I enter in a new row that it goes in the proper place (order the data as it enters the database),

Or should I try to have the PHP page grab the information in the right order (or try to arrange everything in the right order)?

I don't know how to go about doing this. If there is another method of doing it that will be fine, just let me know if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases don't have any inherent order to the data. If you care about the order of data when you're displaying it, use the `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do the ordering in mysql, let php handle only the display part.

```
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Will print your records by date descending order. Change order accordingly

Comment: I see, so after I connect to the database, but before I select from the database, I can send the mysql table a query that orders it?  what might that look like?

Comment: @user1751570 yes after connecting to the database and while selecting from database you will use `order by` in the same select query so that the result will already be ordered and you can just display it using php. For e.g. `SELECT `col` FROM `youTableName` ORDER BY `date` DESC`

Answer (score 1):

When you select the data from your table, you specify its order with [the `ORDER BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY SomeField
```

Natural ordering within the table itself isn't guaranteed.  A clustered index will determine an ordering, which your primary key is probably doing.  But "storing the data in order" isn't really what you're meant to do.  The data is just data, it's not "ordered" until its viewed.  So when viewing the data, you specify the order you want it in.

Comment: the person who answered above you used DESC.  so in 'somefield' would I have a value like ' date DESC '?  or can I only say 'date'?  Im assuming that it will order with the closest approaching date followed by the next closest?

Comment: @user1751570: You can append `ASC` or `DESC` to any `ORDER BY` clause.  By default the sort order would be ascending unless explicitly indicated otherwise.